# count in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to count table users row in laravel 5.3.

Here is my code Controller:

```
public function admin(){
    $jumlah['data'] = DB::table('users')->get();
    return view('admin',$jumlah);
}
```

In view, I call this count with :

```
{{ $jumlah->count() }}
```

Then I run and I get the message:

> Undefined variable: jumlah (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\BiroUmum\resources\views\dashboard\admin.blade.php)

Comment: If jumlah means "sum" or "total" then I'd suggest just doing `$jumlah = DB::table('users')->count();` as your current code will be fetching an array of all the users which you seem to not use anyway. I'd also strongly suggest using english variable names, the rest of the code is in english so it doesn't really make any sense to mix in some other language

Answer (score 2):

You're not setting your variable correctly for view.

Try

```
$jumlah = array();
$jumlah['data'] = DB::table('users')->get();

return view('admin',compact('jumlah'));

//or

return view('admin',['jumlah' => $jumlah]);
```

in view :

```
{{ count($jumlah['data']) }} or {{ $jumlah['data']->count() }}
```

Please refer to the documentation here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#passing-data-to-views

Comment: `DB::table('users')->count();`  this is enough

Comment: Agreed if all he needs is the count, but he might be using the data, and then wanting to display a count.